# Get the name of an ID for two separate columns

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write an SQL statement that would produce the given output:

[image: Table]

So far, I've managed to use INNER JOIN and AND statements to be able to produce part of the table:
[image: Result]

I'm trying to get the city names of Warehouse and Manufacturer according to their foreign keys, but I'm having trouble finding out how to reference the city names in accordance to their respective IDs.

This is what i have managed to do so far:

```
SELECT s.stkName as "Stock Name",
   m.ManID as "Manufacturer City",
   w.WHID as "Warehouse City",
     c.CityName as "Warehouse City",
  s.Sellingprice as "Selling Price"

FROM STOCKITEM s 
INNER JOIN MANUFACTURER4787 m 
 on s.ManID = m.ManID
INNER JOIN WAREHOUSE w 
 on w.CityID = m.CityID
INNER JOIN CITY c 
 on w.CityID = c.CityID
WHERE STKNAME = 'Electric Fan' OR 
STKNAME ='Sun Lounge' OR 
STKNAME ='Whisk Combo' OR 
STKNAME ='Solar Pump' OR 
STKNAME ='Garden Tools'

ORDER BY STKNAME ASC;
```

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hABbv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create alias for `City` while joining, otherwise you only got one city per row.

Try this:

```
SELECT s.StkName as 'Stock Name', cm.CityName as 'Manufacturer City', 
       cw.CityName as 'Warehouse City', s.SellingPrice as 'Selling Price'
FROM STOCKITEM s
INNER JOIN MANUFACTURER m ON s.ManID = m.ManID
INNER JOIN CITY cm on m.CityID = cm.CityID
INNER JOIN WAREHOUSE w ON s.WHID = w.WHID
INNER JOIN CITY cw on w.CityID = cw.CityID
```

Comment: Oh I understand now! This has helped me alot, thank you very much for the explanation!